# Rails Deadline Calculator Help: future date = number input from user + date selected by the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, date, datetime

I am new to Ruby on Rails and am trying to build a deadline calculator that works exactly like this one: ([click here](http://www.deadlinecalculator.com/)).

As you can see from the hyperlinked example, my deadline calculator will allow a user to enter a given number into a form field reflecting the number of days until their deadline. My deadline calculator will then add that number to a given date selected by the user. The calculator will then print the resulting date of the deadline based on these two user inputs.

EXAMPLE: Imagine that a user receives a letter stating, "You have 45 days from 2/5/14 to mail a response to this letter...." and wanted to calculate the date that is equal to 45 days after 2/5/14. The user would input "45" (days) and "2/5/14" (start date) and click a "calculate" button. The website would then display something like, "Your deadline is Saturday, March 22, 2014." So here's what I have so far....

My app/views/pages/about_page.html.erb file contains the following block of code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">

      <%= form_tag do %> 
        <%= number_field_tag 'Days' %>
        <p>AFTER</p>
        <%= date_select('Start', 'start_date') %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Calculate' %>
      <% end %>

      <div>
        <%= @deadline %>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

My app/assets/controllers/pages_controller.rb file contains the following blocks of code:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

* * * * 

def about_page
    @days = params[:Days]
    @start = params[:Start]
    @deadline = 'Print the date that is X days after the start date selected by the user.'
end

* * * * 

private
    def page_params
        params.require(:page).permit(:name, :position, :visible)
    end
```

So, my question is, how do I get Rails to add the user's ":Days" input to the user's "Start" date input and then print the resulting "deadline" date? I have searched endlessly for a solution, but have yet to find anything that clearly explains how to calculate a future date where the user inputs both the start date and the number of days after the start date. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the number of days to a date using the + operator, like

```
Date.today + 10 => Sun, 16 Feb 2014
```

In your case this will translate to

```
@deadline = Date.new(params[:Start][:year].to_i, params[:Start][:month].to_i, params[:Start][:day].to_i) + params[:Days].to_i
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code would ignore the `Days` and `Start` input submitted by the user. Shouldn't the code look something like this `Date.[Start date selected by user here] + [number of Days entered by user here] => Sat, 22 Mar 2014` instead? Also, would this code go in the view file or the controller file?

Comment: The point I wanted to make is you can add, using the + operator, a number of days to a date... You of course have to replace this with your own date and number of days...

Comment: Thanks Danny...your answer led me to a solution! I had to make one modest tweak to your recommended code: I replaced `:year` with `"start_date(1i)"`, `:month` with `"start_date(2i)"`, and `:day` with `"start_date(3i)"`.